# Dynamically scale Cloud Dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've a Cloud Dataflow pipeline that looks like this:

1. Read From Cloud Bigtable
2. Do some transformation
3. Write to GCS

Initially without setting any max workers, dataflow autoscaling would scale to max(1000 nodes) and would put a LOT of stress on our Bigtable cluster. Then I specified some maxNumWorkers to say 100 and it's fine and doesn't put any crazy load on our Bigtable cluster and Stage 1 usually finishes quickly (reading from Bigtable); but Step 2 and 3 with only 100 nodes take significantly longer. Is there anyway I can change **maxNumWorkers** dynamically after the first stage? 
I see apply(Wait.on) but not sure how to utilize it. My beam job looks like this:

```
pipeline
 .apply("Read Bigtable",...)
 .apply("Transform", ...)
 .apply("Partition&Write", ...)
```

I am looking for a way to wait for ***.apply("Read Bigtable",...)*** to finish then increase **maxNumWorkers**. Essentially, my first stage is IO bound and I don't need CPU (workers) but my later stages are CPU bound and I need more CPU (workers).

Comment: Good question, I would also like to know if task-level control over workers is possible

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using file sharding to control the parallelism:

1) keep maxWorker to be 1000
2) right after reading from bigtable, save the data to a sharding of 100
3) Load the data again, do processing, but for final results, we write to a sharding of 1000.

I cannot guarantee, but it worth a try.